# App that runs algorithm on server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, web-services, web, server

What kind of server and software would it be necessary to create an app (Android/iOS) that could make requests to a server, which would run a machine learning algorithm on each request while using data/images stored in a database(MySQL?) ?

That is to say, the user would send some data to the server, which would run some machine learning algorithm on this data and some other data obtained from a database, and then send a response to the user.

The algorithm on the server should run in some language like C/C++, and use some library like or software like OpenBR.

PS: could something like Microsoft Azure or Amazon web services be useful?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google App Engine for running machine learning algorithm and use that as a backend to your mobile application. You can use this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial/) on how to do this.